# Is there such a thing as an optional &?

Tags: css, sass

Consider the following code:

```
@mixin bar() {
    @if & {
        &.bar {
            display: none;
        }
    } @else {
        .bar {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}

@include bar();

.foo {
    @include bar();
}
```

...which compiles to:

```
.bar {
    display: none;
}

.foo.bar {
    display: none;
}
```

Is there a way to write this mixin without duplicating the `.bar` block?

Answer (score -1):

You can consider it as an argument with a default value that you can easily change:

```
@mixin bar($c:'.bar') {
    @if & {
        &#{$c} {
            display: none;
        }
    } @else {
        #{$c} {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The block is still repeated. This doesn’t answer the question